# Collision detection not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm trying to build a simple game and having hard time with collision detecting. I want the alert to be popped up when the hero hits the virus and below is my js code. I'm not sure if my collision detect logic is wrong too. The viruses are moving randomly and I used CSS transition for them to move gradually.

```
var henryLocation = {
    top: 700,
    left: 700
}

document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    // console.log(evt)
    if (evt.keyCode === 38 && henryLocation.top > 10) {
        henryLocation.top = henryLocation.top - 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && henryLocation.top < 700) {
        henryLocation.top = henryLocation.top + 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 37 && henryLocation.left > 10) {
        henryLocation.left = henryLocation.left - 25
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 39 && henryLocation.left < 1360) {
        henryLocation.left = henryLocation.left + 25
    }
    moveHenry()
}

function moveHenry () {
    document.getElementById('henry').style.top = henryLocation.top + 'px'
    document.getElementById('henry').style.left = henryLocation.left + 'px'
}

const startBtn = document.getElementById('btn-start')
startBtn.addEventListener("click", theGame)

function theGame () {
    const startGame = setInterval(moveCorona, 1300)
    
    function moveCorona () {
    const theCorona = document.getElementById('corona')
    const theCorona1 = document.getElementById('corona1')
    const theCorona2 = document.getElementById('corona2')
    const w = 1300, h = 600

    theCorona.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    theCorona1.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona1.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    theCorona2.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + 'px'
    theCorona2.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + 'px'
    

    function collisionDetect () {
        var theHenry = henry.getBoundingClientRect();
        var theCorona = corona.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        if ((theCorona.top > theHenry.top && theCorona.top < theHenry.bottom) || (theCorona.bottom > theHenry.top && theCorona.bottom < theHenry.bottom)) {
            let verticalCollision = true
        } else {
            let verticalCollision = false
        }

        if ((theCorona.right > theHenry.left && theCorona.right < theHenry.right) || (theCorona.left < theHenry.right && theCorona.left > theHenry.left)) {
            let horizontalCollision = true
        } else {
            let horizontalCollision = false
        }

        if (verticalCollision && horizontalCollision) {
            alert('collision detected')
        } else {
            console.log('Game goes on')
        }
    }
    // collisionDetect()
}
}


function gameLoop () {
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000)
}

gameLoop()
```

Comment: That or condition `||` looks suspect. Seems you are doing a "rectangular union" which would include "intersection". Should be an AND condition if so, algorithmically any way

Comment: Also seems to be an error in design to have a sub function with its own scope. That should be its own scope on global. Alternatively, create an object and have that declared as a method. Will upvote this anyway, good question.

Comment: You declared `verticalCollision` and `horizontalCollision` inside an `if` statement, and both are block-scoped so neither is accessible from outside...

Comment: I don't see how this code actually does anything anyway. I assume the function passed to `setTimeout` inside `gameLoop` must be `theGame` in your actual code, rather than `gameLoop` itself. [Actually it can't - or at least shouldn't - be that either, otherwise the `setInterval` on `moveCorona` will keep getting called over and over again.]

Comment: your actual collision detection can be simplified by reversing the logic to determine that they are NOT colliding and then reversing that.  See this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNV-xEMALr8
but basically if you are completely out of range in at least one of the cardinal directions, there is no collision.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is or statement  it should be and statement:

```
if ((theCorona.top > theHenry.top && theCorona.top < theHenry.bottom) && (theCorona.bottom > theHenry.top && theCorona.bottom < theHenry.bottom)) {
  let verticalCollision = true
} else {
  let verticalCollision = false
}

if ((theCorona.right > theHenry.left && theCorona.right < theHenry.right) && (theCorona.left < theHenry.right && theCorona.left > theHenry.left)) {
  let horizontalCollision = true
} else {
  let horizontalCollision = false
}
```